# Dynamically pass patched function to unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a router function which takes a CLI command and executes the corresponding function:

```
def router(value)
    actions = {
        "in": in_action,
        "out": out_action,
    }
    actions[value]()
```

I'm looking to write a test that checks that a given input value executes the correct function. I can do this when there is only a single function that can be called:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("value, exp_count", [ ("in", 1), ("invalid", 0) ] )
@patch("app.handlers.in_action")
def test_router(mock_in_action, value, exp_count):

    app.router(value)

    assert mock_in_action.call_count == exp_count
```

What I am struggling to figure out is whether I can use parametrize to set which function I expect to have been called. Thus allowing me to check multiple possible input values and have the assert statement check the call_count for correct mocked function.

I tried having the parametrize point to the mocked function, but it couldn't pick it up.
I have tried adding the mocked function to a @fixture, with the idea that it'd be accessible to the parametrize. This kind of worked, but the object was a Generator and I couldn't use any assert_call methods on it.

I think I'm either really close, or doing entirely the wrong thing! Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I got around it with a context manager for `patch`.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("value, exp_count, func", [ ("in", 1, "in_action"), ("out", 1, "out_action" ] )
def test_router(value, exp_count, func):
    with patch("app.handlers." + func) as mock_action:
        app.router(value)
        assert mock_action.call_count == exp_count
```

This solution assumes the functions `in_action` and `out_action` are defined in the same module as `router`.

Another issue, with your code as written, is testing `"invalid"` will raise a `KeyError`. I would handle that in a separate test.